# How to get Gitlab merge request description in Gitlab CI?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to fetch the description of the merge request to generate changelog. Is it possible to get the description??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [GitLab CI/CD's predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) there are some variables related to merge requests, such as:

```
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ASSIGNEES
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_CHANGED_PAGE_PATHS
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_CHANGED_PAGE_URLS
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_PROJECT_PATH
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_PROJECT_URL
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_REF_PATH
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_PROJECT_ID
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_PROJECT_PATH
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_PROJECT_URL
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE

⋮
```

You can easily access them inside pipelines and jobs.

**EDIT**:
It seems there is no variable to access the merge requests description. I think using [GitLab's Merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr) can be helpful. So by requesting below URL inside your pipeline (using `curl` or other tools) you will get access to more information about a single merge request:

```
GET    $CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
```

Comment: Hey! They don't provide a predefined environment variable for Merge Request description.

Comment: I'll try that one!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-defined Gitlab CI/CD variable for `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`. If you're triggering a job once the merge request is accepted into the target branch, the merge commit message will be stored in the `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` variable.

You can update the "merge commit message template" in the repo settings to contain the merge request description in the merge commit.

```
Merge branch '%{source_branch}' into '%{target_branch}'

%{title}

%{description}

See merge request %{reference}
```

Then you can just reference the `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` variable in your YAML file to generate the changelog.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the predefined Gitlab variable `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION`. It only works in merge request pipelines so you should also add

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

to the job. More info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION` was just added apart of GitLab version 16.7

Answer (score 0):

See [GitLab 16.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-description) (January 2024):

> ### Predefined variables for merge request description
>
> If you use automation to work with merge requests in CI/CD pipelines, you might have wanted an easier way to fetch a merge request’s description without an API call.
>
> In GitLab 16.7 we introduced the `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION` predefined variable, making the description easily accessible in all jobs.
>
> In GitLab 16.8 we tweaked the behavior to truncate `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION` at 2700 characters, because very large descriptions can cause runner errors.
> You can check if the description was truncated with the newly introduced `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION_IS_TRUNCATED` predefined variable, which is set to `true` when the description was truncated.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/432846).