# Merge Request API in GitLab CI/CD returning unauthorized error

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

i found the answer:
[How to get Gitlab merge request description in Gitlab CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769827/how-to-get-gitlab-merge-request-description-in-gitlab-ci)

But there is no answer to the request:

```
$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
```

i added a header:

```
PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN
```

Where $TOKEN - CI_BUILD_TOKEN or CI_JOB_TOKEN, but answer:

```
HTTPCode: 401
```

UPD.
I created script:

```
#!/usr/bin.env bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

urlBase="${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID}
echo "[--] urlBase: ${urlBase}"
echo "[--] key + build"
curl "${urlBase}?private_token=${CI_BUILD_TOKEN}"
echo "[--] key + job"
curl "${urlBase}?private_token=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
echo "[--] header + build"
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${CI_BUILD_TOKEN}" "${urlBase}"
echo "[--] header + job"
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" "${urlBase}"
echo "[--] header2 + build"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${CI_BUILD_TOKEN}" "${urlBase}"
echo "[--] header2 + job"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" "${urlBase}"
```

but output:

```
{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're calling the GitLab API using cURL, you need to pass the API token explicitly. Read the [GitLab Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#personalproject-access-tokens) carefully, since there are quite a few gotchas.

#### Credentials in cURL Command

Here are some common ways for passing credentials in a cURL command:

As a parameter:

```sh
curl "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID?private_token=<your_access_token>"
```

As a header:

```sh
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"
```

#### CI Job Token

The GitLab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#gitlab-ci-job-token) specifies which API calls can be made with `$CI_JOB_TOKEN`:

> With a few API endpoints you can use a GitLab CI/CD job token to authenticate with the API: Packages, Artifacts, Pipeline Triggers, Release Creation, Terraform Plan.

Note that **Merge Request** is not in that list, so that won't work.

#### CI Build Token

According to this [issue](https://github.com/JanMikes/gitlab-ci-push-to-gcr/issues/1#issuecomment-574097912), `$CI_BUILD_TOKEN` was deprecated in GitLab 9.x and was renamed to `$CI_JOB_TOKEN`, so that won't work either.

#### Personal Access Token

You can authenticate to a GitLab API using [Personal Access Tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html), or PATs. First, create your PAT using these [instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token). Make sure you select **api** as the scope. Then, add the token to a GitLab variable following these [instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/ci/variables/#via-the-ui). Make sure you enable "Mask Variable" so that your token is not exposed in logs. Now, in `gitlab-ci.yml`, the variable you created will be available as an environment variable.

Comment: Personal Access Token! Thanks!